# c# MailMessage object question

Tags: c#

I have a a MailMessage object called message.

I am trying to create the message.Body but I only have a IList to populate it with.

In the body I want the following:

```
"The following files could not be converted-" + IList<string> testlist
```

??????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("The following files could not be converted-\n");
foreach(string s in testlist)
    builder.AppendFormat("{0}\n", s);

string body = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: how would I add a string after the testlist as well?

Comment: Also I need the list seperated by commas is that possible?

Comment: If all you want is a CSV string, why not just convert your list to a CSV string.  Example: string.Join(",", new List<string>(strings).ToArray());

Answer (score 0):

```
var body = string.Format("The following files could not be converted-{0}.", string.Join(", ", testlist.ToArray()));
```

you can play around with the layout by using "\n" instead of ", " for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert your IList to a CSV string value.  The string.Join() function should help with this.

Below is code off the top of my head, so it may not work, but hopefully it gives you the idea.

```
IList<string> x = new List<string>();
x.Add("file1");
x.Add("file2");

string message = "The following files could not be converted: " + string.Join(", ", x.ToArray());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, IList doesn't have the ToArray() method.

Answer (score -1):

This is free-hand and untested, but you get the idea...

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("The following files could not be converted:\n");
testlist.ForEach(s => sb.Append(string.Format("{0}\n", s)));
```

Comment: i think you forgot to add line breaks in between your entries.

Comment: @Paul Sasik: As I said, he should get the idea.  Note also that the original pseudo-code in the question didn't involve line breaks.  I figured formatting wasn't the most important part.